# socket connection code of php

Tags: php, sockets

I am writing a simple php socket code.
Here is my code

```
 <?php

    $address="127.0.0.1";
    $port=9875;
    echo "I am here";

    if(false==($socket=  socket_create(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP)))
    {
        echo "could not create socket";
    }
    socket_bind($socket, $address, $port) or die ("could not bind socket");
    socket_listen($socket);
    if(($client=socket_accept($socket)))
        echo "client is here";

    ?>
```

when I run this program my browser only shows waiting for localhost.
Is there any problem in my code?
I am using xammp 1.7.4 .
Another thing I want to know if I want to get a HTTP or FTP request do I have change only the port number?

Comment: Please improve your English, avoid greetings and thank yous and avoid writing with excessive question marks.

Comment: Tried to close the socket after you're done using it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I verified the code and tested in my system and it works correctly. Showing as "client is here" after running the client.

File Name: server.php

```
<?php
    $address="127.0.0.1";
    $port=9875;
    echo "I am here";
    set_time_limit (0); 
    if(false==($socket=  socket_create(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP)))
    {
        echo "could not create socket";
    }
    socket_bind($socket, $address, $port) or die ("could not bind socket");
    socket_listen($socket);
    if(($client=socket_accept($socket)))
        echo "client is here";

    socket_close($socket); 
    ?>
```

First run the server.php file.

File: client.php

```
<?php
$host="127.0.0.1" ;
$port=9875;
$timeout=30;
$sk=fsockopen($host,$port,$errnum,$errstr,$timeout) ;
if (!is_resource($sk)) {
    exit("connection fail: ".$errnum." ".$errstr) ;
} else {

    echo "Connected";
    }
?>
```

Now run the client.php

Your output should be like this (as I got in my system)

> I am hereclient is here

If not, make sure your firewall is not blocking the request. Temporarily disable antivirus if you have one.

Comment: It works. Thanks. Can you give me your mail address so that I can keep contact with you? I am new to php . So I am having some problem . Can you help me out ?

Comment: Nice to know it works. You always can post your queries in stackoverflow or contact me in facebook,

Answer (score 3):

That is the expected behaviour of waiting.
The program you have written is a socket server which is ready to listen to the connection with the specified port, until then it will wait.

You can create a client who connects so that you will see the response "Client is here". The client can be any programming language including PHP.

Below is a sample code in PHP (I didn't verify it).

```
$fp = stream_socket_client("127.0.0.1:9875", $errno, $errstr);

if (!$fp) {
    echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
} else {
   // Handle code here for reading/writing
}
```

You can check [this link](http://snipplr.com/view/1677/php-socket-client/) for sample client code in PHP.

**EDIT**

```
$host = "127.0.0.1";
$port = 9875;
$timeout = 30;
$sk = fsockopen($host, $port, $errnum, $errstr, $timeout);
if (!is_resource($sk)) {
    exit("connection fail: " . $errnum . " " . $errstr);
} else {
    echo "Connected";
}
```

Comment: I also write a client file. But it can't  reach the server. It is showing the error "unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:9875 (No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it."

Comment: are you running another page as client? make sure you start the server first. Can you try the edited code in my answer

Comment: I am running another page as client also start the server first and tried your code .But still the same error .