# PHP socket programming problem

Tags: php, sockets

I have developed a socket server using `C#` and a client in `PHP` which connects fine  .. i just need to send some data from the client to the server.

I developed the PHP socket client as according to this [Past Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054059/socket-connection-code-of-php)

```
<?php
$host="127.0.0.1" ;
$port=9875;
$timeout=30;
$sk=fsockopen($host,$port,$errnum,$errstr,$timeout) ;
if (!is_resource($sk)) {
    exit("connection fail: ".$errnum." ".$errstr) ;
} else {

    echo "Connected";
    }
?>
```

Finally What i required is to send a data (byte array) to the socket server using this **PHP client**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`fwrite()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php), see as well the manual page for [`fsockopen()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php) for examples.

```
$bytesWritten = fwrite($sk, $string);
```

If you have an array of bytes, convert it to string before writing:

```
$string = imlode('', $byteArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [PHP Documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.fsockopen.php#refsect1-function.fsockopen-examples):

```
fwrite($sk, 'A message sent to the server');
```

Or with arrays :

```
$array = array(4, '3', 'Foo');
fwrite($sk, serialize($array)); //You'll have to deserialize it on C# side.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$msg = "Your message here";

fwrite($sk, $msg);
// Only if you expect some response
while (!feof($sk)) {
    echo fgets($sk, 128);
}
// Close the stream
fclose($sk);
```